# Move node_modules folder to different location?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, create-react-app

I want to use various cloud sync services to safely backup my project and keep it updated on the cloud. But I do not want to sync the `node_modules` folder. I am working with a React project setup using `create-react-app`.

So how can I move the `node_modules` folder from the project folder to anywhere else on my system? What changes do I need to make in my project files and how can I use `npm start` to launch hot-reload server like I normally do?

Comment: Are you looking to use something like `github` ?

Comment: @RachitAnand i can use that but i prefer cloud sync bcoz of their simplicity and auto-sync